# Taking screenshots and display in new popup / tab in Angular 1.6

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am new to Angular I wanted to achieve below scenario.

When I click a button I need to take a screenshot (in jpeg format or any other image format) of the page and display the screenshot in new tab/popup window using Angular 1.6.

Here is the sample code I have tried.

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#myButton').on('click', function() {
            $("p").clone().appendTo("body");
        });
    });
</script>


<body ng-app="screenApp">
    <div>
        <p id="main">
        <img src="cat.jpg" height="300" width="300"/>
        </p>
        <div ng-controller="screenController">
            <div>
                <button id="myButton" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="capture()">Click</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**modal-form.html**

```
<form name="form.userForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div>
            <label>To</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="name" required>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Bcc</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" ng-model="user.username" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="8" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Subject</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="email" required>
        </div>


        <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" cols="85">
            <div id="copy"></div>   
        </textarea>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="form.userForm.$invalid">Send</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("screenApp", [ 'ui.bootstrap' ]);
app.controller("screenController", [ '$scope', '$modal', '$log',

function($scope, $modal, $log) {
    $scope.capture = function() {
        $scope.message = "Show Form Button Clicked";
        console.log($scope.message);

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl : 'modal-form.html',
            controller : ModalInstanceCtrl,
            scope : $scope,
            resolve : {
                userForm : function() {
                    return $scope.userForm;
                }
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {

            $scope.selected = selectedItem;
        }, function() {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    };
} ]);

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function($scope, $modalInstance, userForm) {
    $scope.form = {}
    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
};
```

Comment: Can you post what code you have already?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use any java script library to take a screenshot of your current page, I would recommend to use [this](http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/take-screenshot-of-a-webpage-using-html5-and-javascript.php) java script library, the example is already added in the link

You need to integrate it to your angular js code and open generated image to the new tab or window,

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.